# How to dynamically display a place holder including translation with conditions angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a dynamic form where i am trying to add the placeholder with conditions along with that i want to include translate pipe.
But the below function is not working
Here i have two conditions in place holder one is dynamic name with asterisk and another is just dynamic key which i need to show based on the translate button below is the link for the code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multilingual-translation-pimwhk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
example: placeholder="{{field[i].is_mandatory
                  ? field[i].field_name_key +  ' *'
                  : field[i].field_name_key | translate}}


Html: 



    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div class="mb-2">
        <small class="text-danger">*</small>
        <small class="pl-1">{{ "REQIREDFIELDS"  }}</small>
      </div>
      <div formArrayName="formData" *ngFor="let item of ordersFormArray.controls; let i = index">
        <ng-container [formGroupName]="i" [ngSwitch]="field[i].type">
          <div class="form-label-group mb-3 textPassword">
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'inputText'">
              <input [type]="field[i].inputType == 'password' ? 'password' : 'text'" autocomplete="off" [formControlName]="field[i].field_name_key" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="
                        {{field[i].is_mandatory
                          ? field[i].field_name_key +  ' *'
                          : field[i].field_name_key | translate}}
                      " autofocus />

            </ng-container>
          </div>


        </ng-container>
      </div>

      <button type="button" [disabled]="!form.valid" class="btn btn-primary btn-block border-0">
            {{ "REGISTER"  }}
          </button>
    </form>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="useLanguage('ta')">  {{'login.button.en' | translate}}  </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="useLanguage('fr')">  {{'login.button.fr' | translate}}  </button>
```

How to add pipe to translation?
Please let me know as i dint any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common issue with ternary operator and translate pipe. You have to evaluate your condition first (wrap it in () ) and then use the translate pipe.

```
placeholder="{{ (field[i].is_mandatory ? field[i].field_name_key_a : field[i].field_name_key_b) | translate}}"
```

This should work when you have two different keys.

EDIT: Now that I understand what are you trying to achieve, try this:

```
placeholder="{{ field[i].field_name_key | translate }}{{ field[i].is_mandatory ? " *" : ""}}"
```

So what you really want to do is translate `field_name_key` and only if it mandatory append " *" to it. In your approach you made a mistake that you appended it to the translation key. So the translate pipe was using for non existing key: `"some.key.to.use *"`

Comment: The one with asterisk doesn't translate

Comment: is it a correct key? the space in it looks suspicious

Comment: yes its a correct key  because of asterisk its not working

Comment: any other solutions?